# Convert UITableViewController to UITable VIew Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, mobile

I currently have a NSArray loading values into a UITableViewController NIB.  I realize that I want to use a table along with other objects in my view, such as labels and buttons etc.  Therefore I need to use a UITableView object within my UIView.

What is the proper way to code this?  Can I copy the methods from my current TabeViewController class to my UIView Class?

```
#import "LogTableViewController.h"


@implementation LogTableViewController
@synthesize logArray;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    logArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Today's Workout", @"Last Workout", @"Past Week", @"Past Month", @"All Workouts", nil];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [logArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel.text = [logArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
    }

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STEP-1**

In your .h(header file), change

```
@interface <viewControllername>:UITableViewController
```

to

```
@interface <viewControllername>:UIViewController
```

**STEP-2:**

In your XIB, remove `tableView` as main view and add a UIView from the library. Connect the `view` Outlet of the File's Owner to that UIView.

Now you can use the ViewController as normal UIViewController class.

Add a tableView to the View now and give its dimensions.

Also you will need to put an outlet to the tableView now as it is no longer a UITableViewController but a UIViewController. Also dont forget to connect table's `datasource` and `delegate` connections to File's owner

Now you can easily put other controls along side the tableView.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Parth, that worked perfectly, thanks!  You are taking over the iPhone section of SO!  And thats a good thing!

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks. It is nothing like taking over the iPhone section. It is a joint effort by all the others including you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like you currently have a UITableViewController subclass and you want to change it to be a UIViewController subclass.

There are a few things that you'll need to go through in order to do this, and hopefully I won't forget any of the steps.

First in your @interface file, change your classes' superclass, conform to the datasource and delegate protocols and finally declare an outlet for a UITableView:

```
@interface YourViewControllerName : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

Move on to your implementation file and @synthesize the tableView property:

```
@implementaion YourViewControllerName
@synthesize myTableView;
```

You also need to change your designated initializer if you do create your viewcontroller programatically and are doing any customisation during it's initialisation (it doesn't seem to be the case for you as you mentioned having a NIB file, but here it is anyway):

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Copy your table view delegate and datasource methods from the old view controller, plus any custom initialisation code for your (NSArray*) data source. This is usually created in your `viewDidLoad:` method.

Move on to your NIB file (the one with the tableview object only). Add a UIView object to the nib and move the table view object as a subview of it.

Connect the UIView to your file owner's view outlet, and the UITableView with the file owner's myTableView outlet by dragging from the file owner to the respective objects. Make the file owner your tableview datasource and delegate but control dragging from the tableview to the file owner.

And unless I'm forgetting something, that should be all you need to do.

Feel free to ask any questions in the comments section.

Cheers,

Rog

Comment: Just a tiny clarification: he won't need to copy his datasource and delegate methods since the new view controller is the old view controller, just with a different superclass. Also, he should nil the tableView outlet in viewDidUnload. You seem to have hit everything else, though.

Comment: I was typing my answer while you might have posted. So I didnt see your answer. Sorry no hard feelings.

Comment: Thanks @Rog.  Your answer is perfect.  Unfortunately I saw Parth's before I saw yours but I'm giving it a +1.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries guys, happy to help when I can!

Answer (score 1):

Parth's answer above was great  - but I had to do one additional thing in my code.

One of the things you lose when you change from a `UITableViewController` to a `UIViewController` is the property `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`. So I added an implementation of `viewDidAppear` as follows:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSArray *selectedRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    if (selectedRows) {
        for (NSIndexPath *selectedPath in selectedRows) {
            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedPath animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
```